# Generating txt file in complex format from Matlab datas

Tags: matlab, text, file-io, formatting

I'm relatively new to Matlab and currently using it to calculate pressure cards for rapid dynamic applications on RADIOSS.
The function is done and can calculate Time-Pressure points.
For the moment I generated only .ascii files to import as curves into the software but I'd like to directly write a text file readable by RADIOSS. (after conversion)

The formatting I need is very specific and I'd like to know if such a thing is possible to do on Matlab. I've been searching on my own for some time now and didn't find really specific formatting options so I come seeking for your advice.

For example I have `n` time Arrays `Te{1 to n}` an `n` Pressure Arrays `Pr{1 to n}` the format needed is presented in the image linked. How can it be done if it is possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) function is quite powerful and should provide all the facilities you need. Having looked at the image you linked, I don't see anything particularly special.

Comment: perhaps should mention `fprintf` since OP is writing to file